# What is the canonical way to return a json object in asp.net webforms programming?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json, webforms

In ASP.Net MVC action methods can return json objects simply by returning something like so:

JSon([whatever])

How do I return a JSon representation of say `List<String>` with webforms either through a service or through a method in the code behind of an aspx page? This seems incredibly confusing compared to ASP.Net MVC.

Comment: "[ASP.Net] seems incredibly confusing..." hear, hear!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at http://json.codeplex.com/ which would allow you do the following:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

List<String> strings = new List<String>();
strings.Add("one");
strings.Add("two");
strings.Add("three");

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(strings);
// same as json = "[\"one\",\"two\",\"three\"]";

json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { mystrings = strings });
// same as json = "{\"mystrings\":[\"one\",\"two\",\"three\"]}";
```

Answer (score 1):

It certainly is a lot more work, that's for sure.

With `return Json(foo)` the MVC framework handles all the serialization.

In ASP.NET Web Forms, such luxury isnt available.

In this case, you need to use the `DataContractSerializer`.

See here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb410770.aspx

And of course, you need to decide how to host your service (WCF, ASMX, ASHX)

That decision is up to you - depending on your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use

1. [ASP.Net AJAX Web Services](http://www.asp.net/ajax/tutorials/understanding-asp-net-ajax-web-services) (which used [JavascriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) like in ASP.net MVC)
2. or WCF and `DataContractSerializer`

And some helpful resources on Ajax Application Architecture:

[AJAX Application Architecture, Part 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163363.aspx)
[AJAX application architecture, Part 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163347.aspx)